# update a table when new data is available in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table: 
[image]

Am using this query to populate my **marks** table with all 'id' in **student** table:

```
$module1= "insert into marks (stud_id,moduleID) 
           select sid, 1 
            from user_student 
            where sid not in (
                select * from (
                     select distinct stud_id from marks where moduleID=1
                ) alias_name
             )";
```

So i need to take all 'sid' from Table **student** and populate them into table **marks** my query above does all that. The problem am encountering is that every time i make a change to the data e.g column **test1** , new record are inserted again.

If i populate the marks table manually, Can't i have a code that when new data is available in student table, the data is just updated in marks table...

Comment: I think a database trigger may be best for what you are trying to do.  Suggest querying to see if the record exists and if the result set is 0, insert; else, update

Comment: The new records are inserted because you are calling `insert` again in your application.  At the very least, you could put a unique index on `marks(stud_id)` (if that is what you intend) to prevent duplicates.  More likely, you don't need a `marks` table at all, just a view to return the appropriate results from `students`.

Comment: You need to redesign the database and use 3NF

Comment: Hello, @GordonLinoff, if i refresh the page, the record is not inserted again, only when i modify for e.g test1 data, then it is inserted one again... A simple solution will be to update the **marks** table whenever new record is added to the student table... Can anyone write the code that i need to use to update the mark table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand some points of your insert query, why insert `sid` in `stud_id` if there's a `id` in student table to relate them?

Maybe solve your problem the creation of a composed unique key to `moduleID` and `stud_id` and use a `REPLACE` in place of `INSERT`.

But the right way to do it is using a `TRIGGER` like:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `student_after_insert`;
CREATE TRIGGER `student_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `student` 
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO marks (stud_id,moduleID) 
 SELECT NEW.`id`, `modules_table`.`id` FROM `modules_table`;
```

PS: I suppose you have a table of modules with name `modules_table`. Change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understand your question at the best, my tip is:

Make a unique constraint on `marks` table (up to you is the choice of best constraint rule). 
Then use a trigger to make the right insert/update:
Something like that, (hope that syntax is right):

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    // check that insertion doesn't broke the constraint previously define, then 
    insert into marks (stud_id,moduleID) values (new.sid, 1);
END
```

Note: NEW is the row that you have as soon inserted/updated on students. Similar you have OLD metarow.

Comment: I need to run this in my sql in pg admin or embed it into a php code?

Comment: You need to run this in the same way you run the create table command. Exactly once.
Read the manual about trigger.

Comment: That what am doing but: 

_#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 6_

Comment: Use ; before the end clause. Anyway you should customize my tip not execute it directly.